# Can Quartz JobExecutionContext getScheduledFireTime() return null value?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am trying to call getScheduledFireTime() on JobExecutionContext object of Quartz.  But, I am getting a null value.

Additional info: I am using [quartz-mongodb](https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb) jobstore.

This happens only during the first time a trigger fires.

Is it correct?  If so, under what situations does Quartz return null for this value?

Comment: After a sleepless night, I found out that it is a bug in [quartz-mongodb](https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb) jobstore.  Created a [pull request]https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb/pull/69) with the fix.  Waiting for the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a sleepless night, I found out that it is a bug in [quartz-mongodb](https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb) jobstore. Created a [pull request](http://www.github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb/pull/69) with the fix. Waiting for the next release of the job store.